# Total number of possible triangles from n numbers

Tags: c, complexity-theory

If `n` numbers are given, how would I find the total number of possible triangles? Is there any method that does this in less than `O(n^3)` time?

I am considering `a+b>c`, `b+c>a` and `a+c>b` conditions for being a triangle.

Comment: Hint: sort the numbers, and for each couple `(a,b) (b≥a)` find all `c`s that satisfy `b≤c≤a+b`.

Comment: but in worst case, even in avg case we will get O(n^3) complexity ? Or may be i am mis-understood. Can u elaborate ?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Assume there is no equal numbers in given n and it's allowed to use one number more than once. For example, we given a numbers {1,2,3}, so we can create 7 triangles:

1. 1 1 1
2. 1 2 2
3. 1 3 3
4. 2 2 2
5. 2 2 3
6. 2 3 3
7. 3 3 3

*If any of those assumptions isn't true, it's easy to modify algorithm.*

**Here I present algorithm which takes O(n^2) time in worst case:**

1. Sort numbers (ascending order).
   We will take triples ai <= aj <= ak, such that i <= j <= k.
2. For each i, j you need to find largest k that satisfy ak <= ai + aj. Then all triples (ai,aj,al) j <= l <= k is triangle (because ak >= aj >= ai we can only violate ak < a i+ aj).

Consider two pairs (i, j1) and (i, j2) j1 <= j2. It's easy to see that k2 (found on step 2 for (i, j2)) >= k1 (found one step 2 for (i, j1)). It means that if you iterate for j, and you only need to check numbers starting from previous k. So it gives you **O(n)** time complexity for each particular i, which implies **O(n^2)** for whole algorithm.

C++ source code:

```
int Solve(int* a, int n)
{
    int answer = 0;
    std::sort(a, a + n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int k = i;

        for (int j = i; j < n; ++j)
        {
            while (n > k && a[i] + a[j] > a[k])
                ++k;

            answer += k - j;
        }
    }

    return answer;
}
```

**Update for downvoters:**

This definitely is O(n^2)! Please read carefully "An Introduction of Algorithms" by Thomas H. Cormen chapter about Amortized Analysis (17.2 in second edition). 
**Finding complexity by counting nested loops is completely wrong sometimes.** 
Here I try to explain it as simple as I could. Let's fix *i* variable. Then for that *i* we must iterate *j* from *i* to *n* (it means O(n) operation) and internal while loop iterate *k* from *i* to *n* (it also means O(n) operation). **Note: I don't start while loop from the beginning for each *j***. We also need to do it for each i from *0* to *n*. So it gives us  **n * (O(n) + O(n)) = O(n^2)**.

Comment: so your while loop runs for free ? have you counted complexity of while loop, since only 2 for will give O(n^2)

Comment: Guys, please read my update and look more careful. It is O(n^2).

Comment: my apologies .. I have corrected my mistake also upvoted and accepted this as answer :-)

Comment: can't we use binary search to find the value of 'k'? this would reduce time complexity to nlogn?

Comment: @Wisdom'sWind Your solution is a piece of art. Down voters try understanding the way k is being moved. It's not reinitialized in the while loop every time, that's how the algorithm achieved O(n^2) complexity

Comment: @shivi No using binary search won't give you a complexity of O(nlogn).Why? Because your outerloop (i) runs for n times. Your loop for k runs n times and your loop with j also runs for n times. If you change k to binary search , it will run for logn time but your complexity will still be O(n^2) because your loops inside will have a complexity of O(n)+O(logn) = O(n). Yeah ! It will be more efficient though

Comment: great answer and clever runtime analysis

Comment: @Shivendra correct me if I'm wrong, but I think applying B-Search on 'k' would yield an avg. case complexity of O(nlogn) but the worst case time complexity of O(n^2logn)...?

Answer (score 5):

There is a simple algorithm in `O(n^2*logn)`.

- Assume you want all triangles as triples `(a, b, c)` where `a <= b <= c`.
- There are 3 triangle inequalities but only `a + b > c` suffices (others then hold trivially).

And now:

- Sort the sequence in `O(n * logn)`, e.g. by merge-sort.
- For each pair `(a, b), a <= b` the remaining value `c` needs to be at least `b` and less than `a + b`.
- So you need to count the number of items in the interval `[b, a+b)`.

This can be simply done by binary-searching a+b (`O(logn)`) and counting the number of items in `[b,a+b)` for every possibility which is b-a.

All together `O(n * logn + n^2 * logn)` which is `O(n^2 * logn)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but complexity is right here. BTW, @cartesius00, you know the index of b, no need to binary-search it.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a binary sort, that's O(n-log(n)), right?  Keep your binary tree handy, and for each pair (a,b) where a b and c < (a+b).

Comment: this will always evaluate to false, see my answer

Comment: @artistoex - if you are referring to your paragraph about inequalities and symmetry, that has some serious flaws.  Is it some sort of joke?

Comment: @david actually no, not a joke :-) yes, that was a bit rash.

Comment: @david: Sorry, but this is not an answer and `O(n-log(n))` stuff is incorrect.

Comment: @James I understood that mistakenly it was n-long(n) and should be O(n logn), since no pram algorithm can sort in less than this. Moreover this gave me enough idea to reduce complexity from O(n^3) to O(n^2 logn). So I mark this correct. Whoever negates the answer should undo this.

Comment: @James, sorry I didn't mean to imply the whole algorithm was O(n-logn), just the sort part.

Answer (score 2):

Let a, b and c be three sides. The below condition must hold for a triangle (Sum of two sides is greater than the third side)

```
i) a + b > c
ii) b + c > a
iii) a + c > b
```

**Following are steps to count triangle.**

1. Sort the array in non-decreasing order.
2. Initialize two pointers ‘i’ and ‘j’ to first and second elements respectively, and initialize count of triangles as 0.
3. Fix ‘i’ and ‘j’ and find the rightmost index ‘k’ (or largest ‘arr[k]‘) such that ‘arr[i] + arr[j] > arr[k]‘. The number of triangles that can be formed with ‘arr[i]‘ and ‘arr[j]‘ as two sides is ‘k – j’. Add ‘k – j’ to count of triangles.

Let us consider ‘arr[i]‘ as ‘a’, ‘arr[j]‘ as b and all elements between ‘arr[j+1]‘ and ‘arr[k]‘ as ‘c’. The above mentioned conditions (ii) and (iii) are satisfied because ‘arr[i] < arr[j] < arr[k]'. And we check for condition (i) when we pick 'k'

4.Increment ‘j’ to fix the second element again.

Note that in step 3, we can use the previous value of ‘k’. The reason is simple, if we know that the value of ‘arr[i] + arr[j-1]‘ is greater than ‘arr[k]‘, then we can say ‘arr[i] + arr[j]‘ will also be greater than ‘arr[k]‘, because the array is sorted in increasing order.

5.If ‘j’ has reached end, then increment ‘i’. Initialize ‘j’ as ‘i + 1′, ‘k’ as ‘i+2′ and repeat the steps 3 and 4.

**Time Complexity:** O(n^2). 
*The time complexity looks more because of 3 nested loops. If we take a closer look at the algorithm, we observe that k is initialized only once in the outermost loop. The innermost loop executes at most O(n) time for every iteration of outer most loop, because k starts from i+2 and goes upto n for all values of j. Therefore, the time complexity is O(n^2).*

Answer (score 1):

I have worked out an algorithm that runs in O(n^2 lgn) time. I think its correct...
The code is wtitten in C++...

```
int Search_Closest(A,p,q,n)  /*Returns the index of the element closest to n in array 
                                  A[p..q]*/

{
   if(p<q)
   {
      int r = (p+q)/2;
      if(n==A[r])
         return r;
      if(p==r)
         return r;
      if(n<A[r])
         Search_Closest(A,p,r,n);
      else 
         Search_Closest(A,r,q,n);
   }
   else
      return p;
 }



   int no_of_triangles(A,p,q) /*Returns the no of triangles possible in A[p..q]*/
   {
      int sum = 0;
      Quicksort(A,p,q);  //Sorts the array A[p..q] in O(nlgn) expected case time
      for(int i=p;i<=q;i++)
          for(int j =i+1;j<=q;j++)
           {
               int c = A[i]+A[j];
               int k = Search_Closest(A,j,q,c);
               /* no of triangles formed with A[i] and A[j] as two sides is (k+1)-2 if A[k] is small or equal to c else its (k+1)-3. As index starts from zero we need to add 1 to the value*/
               if(A[k]>c)
                    sum+=k-2;
               else 
                    sum+=k-1;
            }
       return sum;
   }
```

Hope it helps........

Comment: I had a similar solution, except I was searching for the closest pair of sides, not the closest single side. The problem with these solutions is that they produce/count same triangles multiple times (e.g. triplets 3<4+5, 4<3+5 and 5<3+4 describe the same triangle but are all counted). Once you try to eliminate duplicate triangles, you instantly hit O(n*n*n) complexity.

Comment: that's why we remove duplicacy prior to checking the condition. Like once we have 3,4,5; we never go back to 4,5,3. Like i=0; i<n;i++ then j=i+1;j<n;j++

Comment: @Peeyush: I ran the above code as-is and mine with duplicates suppressed. The above code clearly produced more solutions than there really were.

Answer (score 1):

[possible answer](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-of-triangles-possible/)

Although we can use binary search to find the value of 'k' hence improve time complexity!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Shai it is the link to counting number of triangles  from an array!

Comment: @shivi they too have given this SO link as reference ... one more loop now ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
N0,N1,N2,...Nn-1
sort
X0,X1,X2,...Xn-1 as X0>=X1>=X2>=...>=Xn-1
choice X0(to Xn-3) and choice form rest two item x1...
choice case of (X0,X1,X2)
check(X0<X1+X2)
OK is find and continue
NG is skip choice rest
```

Comment: what about complexity ? choice function chooses X0 , X1 and X2, due to this, it remains O(n^3), though for some cases because of skipping we can save time, but not always.

Comment: If all is OK combination(worst case?), all combinations must be examined (unskipable) as you might think,　but (X0, X1, X2) as if the skip when NG, (X0, Xn-2, Xn -1) is OK when check process skip able. so you can something skip any case.

Comment: so do you think that skipping few cases will reduce the complexity ?

Comment: Well, I think the effect is lost and the procedure is too complex.

Answer (score -1):

It seems there is no algorithm better than O(n^3). In the worst case, the result set itself has O(n^3) elements.

For Example, if n equal numbers are given, the algorithm has to return n*(n-1)*(n-2) results.

Comment: funny, could have been much funnier, c>d and c>a-b doesn't imply d>a-b :-).

Comment: @peeyush now, that's a valid result (so I hope) :-)

Comment: I removed the former part of my answer so as not to cause confusion.

Comment: @peeyush n^logn is way more than _any_ polynomial

Comment: Edited : i think David's explanation gives (n^2 logn) algorithm, since even in case of n equal no it will work, and finding c can be done in logn time for each a and b.